# C++ input compilation error

Tags: c++, input, output

I was trying to make a C++ input file on Ideone.com, an online compiler.  The program is meant to take in a users input of inches and convert it to centimeters.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
         int inches;
         float centimeters = 2.54;
         float convert;
         cout << "Input inches: ";
         cin >> inches;
         convert = inches * centimeters;
         cout << inches << "as centimeters is "<< convert;
return 0;
}
```

But when I compile this on the website, I cant input anything and i get this as an output

```
 Input inches: -1218641932as centimeters is -3.09535e+09
```

How did this happen? Is there a code flaw or is it the IDE? Please help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use an online compiler

Comment: Press the "stdin" button and enter your input.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, Where is that? I dont see one.

Comment: @Geto, the compiler wont let me do that

Comment: @Storm: What do you mean you "dont see one"? It's right there, under the box where you write your code, next to the button where you picked the language. Look harder.

Comment: Nvm, i found out how to use the button

Comment: Thank you, sorry for being such a noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a filed to type your input, just below the code area;

> enter input (stdin)

Comment: You need to add in your input before you "ideone it." When I entered 20 into the input field for Storm's code I got the following result: Input inches: 20as centimeters is 50.8